Lexicographically largest incidence matrix
I have simple algorithmic question, but I can't find any source where this algorithm is explained in details.
Let's assume that we have incidence (with 0 and 1 values) matrix of size $m\times n$. Let we apply simultaneously all pairs of row $P_1 \in S_m$ and column $P_2 \in S_n$ permutations to this incidence matrix. Obviously because we have finite ordered set, there exist lexicographically largest value of this matrix.
Question is: what is the best algorithm that allows to find this biggest value?
Example input (Fano plane incidence matrix):

Example output:
$$
1110000 \\
1001100 \\
1000011 \\
0101010 \\
0100101 \\
0011001 \\
0010110
$$

This is similar to lexicographically smallest graph canonization, which is known to be NP-hard, but for bipartite graphs. I think there's a good chance it's NP-hard as well

@DanielWeber Yes, I understand that. Still, graph canonical form (I reimplemented nauty's approach from https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1493 Practical graph isomorphism) produces not lexicographically largest incidence matrix.

Is this related to Complete graph invariant based on integer programming?

It could be related. Still, while looked at your code I spotted that you are iterating over permutations(n). If n>10 it leads to unacceptable running time. Still, nauty runs pretty fast on non-regular graph. I assume that there is (or could be) algorithm which runs with approximately similar time.

I am permuting for a toy implementation. The problem can be formulated to integer program, which is faster than permuting, but still of exponential complexity.

Could you, please, remind us what is the lexicographic order on $m\times n$ $0-1$ matrices? Is it according to reading left to right top to bottom like a page in a book, or something else?

@fedja yes, It's according to reading like a page in a book. You "read" two incidence matrices of same size left to right, top to bottom until you find 1 in one position and 0 in second. Then first matrix is lexicographically bigger. In example above "output" is bigger due to 1 on 3rd position in "output" and 0 on 3rd position in "input".
